# MonoDroid: Satellite assemblies not part of application package

Tags: xamarin.android, resx, satellite-assembly

I'm using MonoDroid to build Android app based on common code shared between WPF/Silverlight/MonoTouch. Strings in that common code are "localized" via RESX -> satellite assemblies. RESX designer is generated via ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx which is the best way to use directly "localized strings" inside WPF/Silverlight XAML.

But coming to Android, the localized string are always the "default" one and not the localized. The satellite assemblies not part of application package. Any hint on what to do to add/link satellite assemblies?

(Of course satellite assemblies are compiled!)

Cheers, Patrick